# HTML form to PDF using node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I want to write a program in node.js such that once I submit the form, downloadable pdf of this form should be generated with user entered inputs.

```
  <form>
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name"  />
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email"  />
      <label for="contact">Contact Number:</label>
      <input type="phone" name="contact" id="contact"  />
      <label for="company">Organization:</label>
      <input type="text" name="company" id="company"  />
      <label for="designation">Designation:</label>
      <input type="text" name="designation" id="designation"  />

      <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PDFKit](https://pdfkit.org)

```
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
const fs = require('fs');

const doc = new PDFDocument();
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.pdf'));

doc
  .fontSize(25)
   // You can use the data as variables 
  .text(`PUT YOUR TEXT HERE AND USE THE DATA LIKE THIS: ${email}`, 100, 100);

doc.end();
```